# PySide slot not run in object's thread

Tags: qt, qt4, pyside, qthread

I'm trying to run a long task in a separate thread in PySide so that the main thread can keep processing GUI events. I have read the proper way to do this is:

- Encapsulate the task in a `QObject` subclass where the work is done in a `run()` method and emits a `finished` signal when done.
- Create a new `QThread` and set the task object's thread affinity to it using `QObject.moveToThread()`.
- Connect the thread's `start` signal to the task's `run()` method.
- Start the thread using `QThread.start()`.

However, I'm running into a strange problem where if the `run()` method is wrapped in a slot, the function will be run in the main thread instead of the thread the object belongs to. If I leave it as a standard Python method, everything works fine.

Here is a minimal example I created:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Task(QtCore.QObject):
    """Does some work and emits a signal when done."""

    finished = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def run1(self):
        """Runs task and emits finished() signal when done."""
        try:
            # Try running the task
            result = self._run()

        except:
            self.finished.emit(None)

        else:
            self.finished.emit(result)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def run2(self):
        """Same as run1, but wrapped in a slot."""
        self.run1()

    def _run(self):
        """Override in subclass"""
        pass


class TestTask(Task):
    """Prints thread ID."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

    def _run(self):
        print('{} thread ID:'.format(self.name), QtCore.QThread.currentThreadId())
        return 'success'


def main():

    gui = QtGui.QApplication([])

    print('Main thread ID: ', QtCore.QThread.currentThreadId())

    # thread1 calls task1.run1()
    task1 = TestTask('task1')
    task1.finished.connect(lambda r: print('Task 1 finished:', r))

    thread1 = QtCore.QThread()
    task1.moveToThread(thread1)

    thread1.started.connect(task1.run1)

    # thread2 calls task2.run2()
    task2 = TestTask('task2')
    task1.finished.connect(lambda r: print('Task 2 finished:', r))

    thread2 = QtCore.QThread()
    task2.moveToThread(thread2)

    thread2.started.connect(task2.run2)

    # Start both threads
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    # Run event loop (doesn't actually return)
    sys.exit(gui.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This produces the following output:

```
Main thread ID:  139962303178496
task1 thread ID: 139961642776320
task2 thread ID: 139962303178496
Task 2 finished success
Task 1 finished success
```

It isn't a huge deal to leave `run()` as a standard Python method, but I'm wondering why this happens. This is with QT4.8 and PySide 1.2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be caused by a possible bug in PySide. The issue seems to be caused by inheriting a base-class that has a decorated slot. If this slot is moved into the subclass, the problem goes away:

```
class TestTask(Task):
    ...

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def run2(self):
        """Same as run1, but wrapped in a slot."""
        self.run1()
```

(PS: as a nother data point, it's worth noting that your original example works fine in PyQt4).

**UPDATE**:

As suspected, this is caused by a known bug in PySide: see [PYSIDE-249](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-249).

Comment: Actually, having the slot with the signature `(object)` is how I originally had it  (which worked), but this was a mistake and left over from when I had the method take an argument. The `QThread.started` signal has no arguments to it, so the slot should have no arguments well. Decorating `run2` with `@QtCore.Slot(int, str, object, int)` also works, despite the obviously incorrect signature. I think because the signature doesn't match the signal it is run as a plain Python function instead of a slot.

Comment: @JaredL. Sorry - I wrote this answer first thing in the morning, and obviously didn't check my reasoning. It's slightly bizarre that my wrong explanation still "worked", though. Anyway, I have looked at this again and I think I have found the real source of the problem - please see my updated answer.

Comment: This appears mostly correct to me, I have verified that everything works as expected when I connected to the `run2()` slot on the base class (after having it print its thread ID as well) but it fails in the subclass which inherits the slot. However, the slot still runs in the main thread when redefining the slot in the subclass. I have tried this with fresh conda environments, one with PySide 1.2.2 and Python 2.7 (`conda create -n pyside-27 pyside`) and another with PySide 1.2.4 from the conda-forge channel and Python 3.6 (`conda create -n pyside-36 -c conda-forge pyside python=3`).

Comment: @JaredL. You should always run a test-case as a stand-alone script, rather than in an IDE or debugger. In my testing, the decorated slot defined in the subclass always runs in the worker thread, whereas it runs in the main thread if inherited from a base-class. This is using python 3.6.2, qt 4.8.7, shiboken 1.2.4, pyside 1.2.4, with the script executed in a normal console (on linux). Please test the script in a similar fashion.

Comment: @JaredL. I have now confirmed this is a bug in pyside: see the update in my answer.

Comment: Looks like this is it! Guess I'll stick to plain methods for now.